# React useRef scrolling just working within setTimeout

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to use scrollIntoView on a react application, and therefore in a page I am using this

```
useEffect(() => {
  myRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
}, [myRef, selectedSectionIndex, modalOpen]);
```

It works on almost every situation as I have the `ref={myRef}` associated to the element that I want to put into view. However, in one of the transitions even if the code is called it does nothing (not even throws an error). Only if I change it to

```
useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => myRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' }), 0);
}, [myRef, selectedSectionIndex, modalOpen]);
```

I have read about similar issues, and that's why I actually tried this solution. But can't really put my finger on how this solves it. I keep reading the referenced dom element might not be rendered yet when the first code runs, but

a. Why would it be on the second one?
b. Putting a debugger just above that line I can see the element is present in the DOM and even more
if I release the debuger, same and silently does nothing but if I step over and run that line it actually scrolls.Edit: I attach a screenshot of the debugger, if I press f8 nothing, if I press f10 it scrolls

I would like to thin there's a cleaner way of making this work but can't find it

Thanks

[image: myRef.current]

Comment: Have you tried to look at the component height before your call, maybe the component did not completely loaded yet.

Comment: Yes @guilhermevictorramalhonatal, and unless I am very wrong it's fine (please find attached image)